# How does one summon specific tropical fish variants in Bedrock Edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I recently was on my world trying to summon specific tropical fish variants via some commands that I found online that were shown to work for Java Edition, however if I attempt to type that same command out on my MineCraft Bedrock world, I would just get an error message.

I've also tried looking everywhere on the internet about if there's any Bedrock Edition alternative commands to spawn specific tropical fish variants but found nothing really of use.

I'm not sure if either there is a Bedrock Edition alternative to the command, or it's another instance of Bedrock Edition missing a command feature.

Regardless though, if anyone knows if there's a way to get the command to work on Bedrock Edition it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for this is as follows (parrot fish eg.):

```
/summon tropicalfish ~ ~ ~ minecraft:become_parrot_fish
```

The different types of tropical fish can be found on the [Wiki page](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tropical_Fish).

Comment: Thank you for this information! This proved to be really helpful for my world's project